# What is the purpose of atomisation in atomic absorption spectroscopy?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

What is the purpose of the atomisation process in atomic absorption spectroscopy?

I understand that solution is evaporated by the flame and then the molecules decompose into atoms.

But why must the molecules become individual atoms before the light is passed through them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement the previous answer:

Atomic absorption lines are very sharp, with high extinction coefficient, low detection limit and are specific for the given element.

Molecular absorption is band-wise, diffuse, with much lower ext. coefficient, higher detection limit and last but not least, the selectivity is lost.

Answer (score 3):

Atomic absorption spectroscopy is a quantitative measure of the elements in the analyte.
We atomise the analyte so that the absorption of light corresponds to the characteristics of the elements. 
Otherwise how we can predict the fundamental elements when these are still part of some molecules?
We measure the absorbance and refer to the Beer-Lambert law.